# SwiftUI, tvOS, UIViewControllerRepresentable and a focus issue

Tags: swiftui, tvos, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to implement search functionality in the tvOS SwiftUI app. I'm using `UISearchController` as the most straight forward solution to do this. I've wrapped it inside `SearchView` which conforms to `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. The problem is, that it looks like the focus engine refuses to focus on a part of a view controller UI - `UISearchBar` that is wrapped. I can type the search query from my Mac, inside the simulator, to verify that the search works, but of course, it's not the real thing.

I've tried to add the `.focusable()` modifier into a `SearchView`, but it didn't help.

Also tried to implement `shouldUpdateFocus`, `preferredFocusEnvironments` and `didUpdateFocus` callbacks inside my custom subclasses of `UISearchController` and `UISearchContainerViewController` but those are not called at all.

I think I'm missing something very straightforward here.

Here is the code for the `SearchView`:

```swift
struct SearchView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UISearchContainerViewController

    typealias Context = UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SearchView>
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: context.coordinator)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = context.coordinator
        return UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: controller)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) { }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchView.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    class Coordinator: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
        
        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }

        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            text = searchText
        }
    
    }

}
```

And the main `ContentView` (I've stripped some non-important code):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var model = ["aa", "ab", "bb", "bc", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
    @State var searchQuery: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        SearchView(text: $searchQuery)
        List {
            ForEach(model.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(searchQuery) })) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: tvOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it can be done through the `.searchable` modifier, introduced in iOS 15 beta 1, no need for `UISearchController` wrappers anymore.

P.S. Got an official response from Apple on this bug (FB8974300) to also use `.searchable` modifier, so there is no fix for the older versions.